# How to manage frame in ruby selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am working with RUBY selenium webdriver (not java, not c#, etc). Please, the solutions must be in ruby. So, I have the frame with Id "_wicket_window_3". To locate this element, I apply:

```
driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(:id, "_wicket_window_3")
```

My frama has the buttons "Adjuntar", "Exportar" and "Terminar".

Now, how can i manage the frame ? I want to click the button "Adjuntar","Terminar" or "Exportar".

If I try there:

```
frame = driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(:id, "_wicket_window_3") 
frame.click_button("Adjuntar")
```

The response is: Undefined method.

Please, help me !!!

Regards, Agustín.

Comment: As you said *Please, the solutions must be in ruby.*, then why other languages are tagged.. I am removinng those.

Comment: What is this `click_button` thing? Why aren't you using something like `driver.find_element(:id,'yourButtonId').click` ?

Comment: After `driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(:id, "_wicket_window_3"`, then find the button `Adjuntar` and click it... Let me know what you see..

Comment: click_button is a method of rwebspec. I haven't got the id of my buttons, so for that i use click_button("Adjuntar").
If I try 
driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(:id, "_wicket_window_3")
driver.click_button("Adjuntar")

The response is: Cannot find the element.

So, I want to assign the frame to one variable and then manage the variable. In this case, the variable is 'frame' but i can't find result.

Comment: In Ruby binding of selenium-webdriver no such method like `click_button` exist. It has only `click`.

Comment: test_case "R34 - Crear un contacto de tipo Operador Online" do
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
try_until(10) {driver.navigate.to "http://10.60.10.36:8181/suaci/login"}

usuario = driver.find_element(:name, "loginUsuario")
usuario.send_keys "grossi"
contraseña = driver.find_element(:name, "loginClave")
contraseña.send_keys "GROSSI4716"
driver.find_element(:name, "ingresar").click
sleep 5

Comment: driver.navigate.to "http://10.60.10.36:8181/suaci/contacto"
sleep 5
ingresar_contacto= driver.find_element(:name, "textoABuscar")
try_until(10) {ingresar_contacto.send_keys "operador online"}
try_until(10) {driver.find_element(:class, "btn").click}
try_until(10) {driver.find_element(:link, "Operador Online").click}
sleep 5

Comment: try_until(10) {driver.find_element(:link, "Adjuntar").click}
#try_until(10) {driver.switch_to.frame"_wicket_window_3" driver.click_button("Adjuntar") }
#aux = driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(:id, "_wicket_window_3") 
#WebElement frame = driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(:id, "_wicket_window_3") 
try_until(10) {driver.switch_to.frame ("_wicket_window_3")}
end

THIS IS MY CODE, RUN IN TEST WISE.

Comment: Ok. But this is not my problem, my problem is that i can't manage my frame. i want assign my frame to a variable and then manage, but i can't. Are there types of data in Ruby ?

Comment: What line is this failing? `click_button` is not a WebDriver method, so you should remove this before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manage the iframe you switched to as you planning. 
When you do

```
driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(:id, "_wicket_window_3")
```

Your context start to be inside this iframe, **all operations you will now do on driver, will be inside this iframe**.

So, after the switch do:

```
driver.click_button("Adjuntar")
```

It should click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think click_button is the right command, that's why the error you get is `undefined method`

you have to switch to the frame then look for the element of that button as you did before to look for the frame, then click it

something like

```
driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(:id, "_wicket_window_3") 
driver.find_element(:id, "id_of_the_button_you_want_to_click").click
```

Note used `:id` there but you can use whatever the locator you want, `:css`, `:xpath`, `:class` whatever